# Looking for this theorem by Devlin and Shelah

Tags: logic, set-theory

This is a theorem of Devlin and Shelah which I am looking for more details and also proof:

---

$2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ is equivalent to the following statement:

There is an $F:H(\aleph_1) \rightarrow 2$ such that, for every $g \colon \omega_1 \rightarrow 2$, there exists an $X \in H(\aleph_2)$ such that, for any $M \prec (H(\aleph_2), \in, X)$ :

$F(\bar{X}) = g(\delta)$.

Here $\bar{X}$ and $\delta$ are the images of $X$ and $\omega_1$, respectively, under the transitive collapse of $M$.

Comment: Have you tried searching [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/)? According to the [Shelah archive](http://shelah.logic.at/Devlin.html), Devlin has been a co-author with Shelah on only four papers.

Comment: Looks like some diamond-like statement. I'd start with the first paper on the list linked by @Arthur.

Comment: I am not sure if the theorem presented in §4 of the paper "A weak version of diamond which follows from $2^{\aleph_0}<2^{\aleph_1}$" will do some work. The first part states the following: If $2^{\aleph_0}<2^{\aleph_1}$ then for each $F\colon 2^{<\omega_1}\rightarrow 2$ there is  a $g \in 2^{<\omega_1}$ s.t. for any $f \in 2^{<\omega_1}$ the set $\lbrace\delta\in\omega_1\colon F(f\upharpoonright\delta)=g(\delta)\rbrace$ is stationary.

Comment: But in this weak version of $\diamondsuit$ the quantifiers are all reversed. Is there a possibility to get from $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{\aleph_1}$  to $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_1}$?

Comment: Negation?${}{}$