# Proof for this equivalent statement to $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ ??

Tags: logic, set-theory

This statement is some kind o a weak form of diamond and I am looking for a proof for its equivalence to $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$.

---

$2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ is equivalent to the following statement **(A)**:

There is an $F:H(\aleph_1) \rightarrow 2$ such that, for every $g \colon \omega_1 \rightarrow 2$, there exists an $X \in H(\aleph_2)$ such that, for any $M \prec (H(\aleph_2), \in, X)$ :

$F(\bar{X}) = g(\delta)$.

Here $\bar{X}$ and $\delta$ are the images of $X$ and $\omega_1$, respectively, under the transitive collapse of $M$.

---

In Devlin/Shelah "A weak version of $\diamond$ which follows from $2^{\aleph_0}<2^{\aleph_1}$", $\Phi$ is the assertion that

$(\Phi)$: 
For each $F \colon 2^{<\omega_1} \to 2$ there is a $g \in 2^{\omega_1}$ such that for any $f \in 2^{\omega_1}$, the set $\lbrace \alpha < \omega_1 \colon F(f \upharpoonright \alpha) = g(\alpha) \rbrace$ is stationary in $\omega_1$

and it is shown that

$2^{\aleph_0}<2^{\aleph_1} \to \Phi$.

---

So when we negate $\Phi$, we get

$(\neg\Phi)$:
There is a $F \colon 2^{<\omega_1} \to 2$ such that for any $g \in 2^{\omega_1}$ there is a $f \in 2^{\omega_1}$, such that the set $\lbrace \alpha < \omega_1 \colon F(f \upharpoonright \alpha) \neq g(\alpha) \rbrace$ contains a club of $\omega_1$.

Using Devlin/Shelah's result it follows that

$2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1} \leftrightarrow \neg\Phi$.

For any $\vec{s} \in 2^{< \omega_1}$ let $F^\ast(\vec{s}) = 1-F(\vec{s})$.

Then

$2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1} \leftrightarrow$ There is a $F \colon 2^{<\omega_1} \to 2$ (namely our $F^\ast$) such that for any $g \in 2^{\omega_1}$ there is a $f \in 2^{\omega_1}$, such that the set $\lbrace \alpha < \omega_1 \colon F(f \upharpoonright \alpha) = g(\alpha) \rbrace$ contains a club of $\omega_1$.

---

Is this valid?
How do I get from here to my original statement (A)?

Comment: It is not my field of interest so I might be wrong, but doesn't $\aleph_1>\aleph_0$ trivially imply $2^{\aleph_1}\color{red}{>}2^{\aleph_0}$ ?

Comment: @Jack: No, it doesn't mean that at all.

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371177/looking-for-this-theorem-by-devlin-and-shelah from a few weeks ago?

Comment: @Asaf: I had problems with the website and could not add any comment. Now I added my attempt but can't get through to my original statement.